# AWS RDS MSSQL logs so many failed login attempts

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

Am pretty new to AWS. I have created RDS with MSSQL express edition and restored few databases into the server with public accessibility as YES and port 1433 and inbound rule allows everyone(0.0.0.0/0) .. after sometime I have observed some fishy login attempts from from **different IP addresses**. in db logs in monitoring section  Is that mean someone trying to get access to my database??

```
2021-07-01 13:36:27.99 Logon       Login failed for user 'sa'. Reason: Could not find a login 
matching the name provided. [CLIENT: 103.41.65.227]
```

Is this expected, can someone throw some light on it.

Answer (score 0):

> with public accessibility as YES and port 1433 and inbound rule allows everyone(0.0.0.0/0)
>
> Is this expected?

You configured a database server to allow the entire Internet to connect and attempt logins. Not sure what other outcome you would expect from this. At a bare minimum you need to lock down that security group to only your IP address. You should seriously look into disabling public accessibility all together, and connect to your database only from your VPC.

Comment: That's true, that's is way to restrict to few applications.. but here my client desktop applications are having direct connections database. All are having dynamic ip addresses.. so it's highly impossible to do this way .

Comment: I would think about redesigning your solution to have your clients connect to an API, possibly served by AWS API Gateway, instead of connecting directly to a database.

Comment: Agree.. that's always the best way.. but here the question is who is trying to access the db frequently , kind of attack ?? The same thing I don't see in Azure, even exposed with full IP range to public..

Comment: You would have to capture some of the IP addresses of the attempted logins and look those up to get an idea who may be trying to login, but it is almost certainly something with malicious intent.